# How to check for json results before passing on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, yql

i have this function to retrieve json data from yql query

```
    function link(b){
        var jsonURI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+encodeURIComponent("select href,alt,content from html where url='"+b+"' and xpath='//a[@id=\"download\"] |//img[@class=\"dvLinkOverlayFill\"] |//meta[@name=\"title\"]'")+"&format=json&diagnostics=true&_maxage=86400&callback=callback&jsoncallback=?";
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
        jQuery.getJSON(jsonURI,callback);
    }
```

What i want is to check if the data is null or not before passing on to the callback, if its null, it runs again the link() function, if not it passes on, i have tried

```
            if (jQuery.query.results == null){link(b);}
```

but no luck, any advice or guide?

EDIT: Got it working, part of it, by using

```
if (o.query.results == null) { link(b); }
```

inside the callback function

```
callback(o){
   if (o.query.results == null) { link(b); }
```

However i can't pass the "b" from the link function to the callback function, it's the only thing that is left for this to work, something like callback(o,b) that could be passed on in here jQuery.getJSON(jsonURI,callback);
 since this one is sending the "o", how to make it send the "b" aswell? something like
jQuery.getJSON(jsonURI,callback(o,b));

Comment: Are you trying to check the results from the YQL json response before calling your link() function which gets the YQL reponse?

Comment: No, i am trying to check the results AFTER the response, if there is no results (null), then try again the function until there are results (link(b))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** updated question answer:

```
    function link(b){
    var jsonURI = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q="+encodeURIComponent("select href,alt,content from html where url='"+b+"' and xpath='//a[@id=\"download\"] |//img[@class=\"dvLinkOverlayFill\"] |//meta[@name=\"title\"]'")+"&format=json&diagnostics=true&_maxage=86400&callback=callback&jsoncallback=?";
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    jQuery.getJSON(jsonURI,function(data, status, xhr){ 
                                            callback(data, status, xhr,b); 
                                    });
}
```

So you got ur b object in arguments[3]

Comment: That's the problem, the reason why sometimes the results returned are null is because those same objects are empty, so your method doesn't work for this case :(

Comment: So you send a request, and sometimes the result is null or an empty objects?, and keep sending until it changes it mind???

Comment: Yes because the target website sometimes fails to send the data so my intention is to keep trying until it passes on

Comment: This doesn't work and i think its because it is trying to find an error which isn't what is happening, the json returns objects any time, the difference is that sometimes the objects exist and others simply don't.

Comment: Thats really strange man, try pasting the whole code here, or better yet create a http://jsfiddle.net/ this way people here could be of more help to u

Comment: I can't thank you enough, thats EXACTLY what i was looking for, thank you very much. Also i had a alert function to warn me if it was working, it showed like tons of alerts instantly, prooving that it was actually working, kinda scared me the amount of alerts lol

Comment: no problem, I suggest you do some reading on closure http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ and a +1 wouldn't hurt ;)

Comment: I wanted to, but when i click it says to login, even tho i am already logged in! How can i do it so i can add u +1?

Comment: if you want start a new stackoverflow question for that so I can answer you :P
I really donno whats happening, if its not working don't bother, happy to be helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just simplify that?

```
if (!jQuery.query.results) { link(b); }
```

Comment: I have tried that but it says that jQuery.query.results is undefined

Comment: If `jQuery.query.results` was undefined, then this would work. Is it saying that `jQuery.query` is undefined?

Comment: I can't tell, it makes the browser crash.